# Values cannot pass from kendo grid to Entity class?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, kendo-grid, kendo-mvvm

Here i my c sharp code of controller api class DefComapny whose value are always null while posting a data from kendo grid thats why not entering any thing to database?

```
   [HttpPost]
    public void SaveDefCompny()
    {
   var result = new List<DefCompany>();
        using (var data = new RPDBEntities())
        {
            DefCompanyDTO productViewModel = new DefCompanyDTO();

                var product = new DefCompany
                {
  //same problem of all entites  getting no value from grid

                 Id = productViewModel.Id, // getting no value from grid
                    CurrentCurrencyCode = productViewModel.CurrentCurrencyCode,
                    ShortName= productViewModel.ShortName,
                    FullName= productViewModel.FullName,
                    ContactPerson= productViewModel.ContactPerson,
                    Address1= productViewModel.Address1,
                    CompanyCity= productViewModel.CompanyCity,
                    CompanyState= productViewModel.CompanyState,
                   CompanyCountry= productViewModel.CompanyCountry,
                   ZipPostCode= productViewModel.ZipPostCode,
                   TelArea= productViewModel.TelArea

                };
               result.Add(product);
               data.DefCompanies.Add(product);

             data.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
```

here is my viewmodel code

```
   document.onreadystatechange = function () {
var viewModel = kendo.observable({

    products: new kendo.data.DataSource({

    schema: {
       //data:"Data",
        total: "Count",

        model: {
            Id: "Id",
            fields: {
                Id: { editable: true, type: "int" },
                ShortName: { editable:true, type: "string" },
                FullName: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                ContactPerson: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                CurrentCurrencyCode: { editable: true, type: "int" },
                Adress1: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                CompanyState: { editable: true, type: "string" },

                CompanyCity: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                CompanyCountry: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                ZipPostCode: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                TelArea: { editable: true, type: "string" }

            }
        }
    },
    batch: true,

    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "/api/Companies/GetAllCompanies",
            dataType: "json"
        },
        create:{

            url: "/api/Companies/SaveDefCompny", 
            dataType: "json"
        },
        update: {
            url: "/api/Companies/SaveDefCompny", // here you need correct api url
            dataType: "json"
        },
        destroy: {
            url: "/api/Companies/Delete", // here you need correct api url
            dataType: "json"
        },
        parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
            if (operation !== "read" && data) {
                 return  kendo.stringify(data) ;


            }
        }
    }

})
});
kendo.bind(document.getElementById("example"), viewModel);


}
```

how should i pass my inline kendo grid values to my controller so that it save it in database?

Comment: DefCompanyDTO productViewModel = new DefCompanyDTO(); 
You've just created the object. Do you expect it to self-populate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Kendo documentation and see what kind of parameters `SaveDefCompny` should expect. You should then be able to read whatever you require using those parameters.

```
url: "/api/Companies/SaveDefCompny", dataType: "json"
```

This most likely is sending your controller method the required data in json format.
Again: your answer lies in the Kendo documentation.

EDIT:
See [this](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.create) and [this](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/ajax-editing).

From their example:

```
public ActionResult Products_Create([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, ProductViewModel product)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (var northwind = new NorthwindEntities())
        {
            // Create a new Product entity and set its properties from the posted ProductViewModel
            var entity = new Product
            {
                ProductName = product.ProductName,
                UnitsInStock = product.UnitsInStock
            };
            // Add the entity
            northwind.Products.Add(entity);
            // Insert the entity in the database
            northwind.SaveChanges();
            // Get the ProductID generated by the database
            product.ProductID = entity.ProductID;
        }
    }
    // Return the inserted product. The grid needs the generated ProductID. Also return any validation errors.
    return Json(new[] { product }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}
```

Comment: Either html or mvc, the data comes in the same way: json. And the parameters are deserialized server-side. As long as your schema from the html code matches your server-side model schema, it should work. Have you tried it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30452503/405-method-not-allowed-when-i-send-json-data-to-string-serialize-data-as-a-par      can you please answer this one related code